# False sharing and Java memory model

Tags: java, multithreading

I am using the example described here https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-concurrency/false-sharing.html where we have the following class:

```
public class Counter {

    public volatile long count1 = 0;
    public volatile long count2 = 0;

}
```

and two threads are each updating the variables count1 and count2 at the same time. Because count1 and count2 are in the same cache line, each time a thread updates one of the variables, the other thread needs to refresh the cache line.

My question is regarding the volatile keyword. The way volatile is usually presented is that when a thread A updates a volatile variable x, and then another thread B reads x, that other thread B is guaranteed to see the updated value of x. But here volatile is used on two different variables. So another property of volatile would be that when a thread A updates a volatile variable, if another thread B then reads any other (also volatile?) variable from the same cache line, then that other thread B needs to refresh the whole cache line?

Comment: Cache lines are a function of hardware, not the Java language.  Your source is talking about a hardware issue, nothing that's forced on the system by the language.

Comment: The article you link to talks about ways to avoid false sharing (a hardware problem).  I'll add there's one more: if you can encourage the optimizer to use a cpu register, you can also avoid updating a field and avoid thrashing the cache.  Assigning a volatile to a local variable as a temporary copy might do the trick.

Comment: It's worse than you think. Using a `volatile` variable establishes a "happens before" relationship between threads. If thread A writes a value to a `volatile`, and then thread B reads that value, the write is said to "happen before" the read. But since everything that happens within any thread must "happen" in "program order," that means, everything thread A did before it wrote the variable must become visible to thread B when B reads the variable—not just whatever else happens to affect the same cache line, but literally _everything._

Comment: If the first thread updates variable count1, and the second thread reads variable count2, only count1 needs to be volatile for the cache line to be refreshed, or count2 needs to be volatile as well?

Answer (score 1):

Both variables need to be volatile. Caches on modern CPUs are always coherent. So it doesn't matter if a cache line is falsely shared or not since the cache ensures coherence. It is the compiler that can still mess things up.

If there is data race, then the JMM allows for any written value to be seen the read is in data race with (*). So imagine the following example:

```
class FalseSharing{
   int a;
   volatile int b;
}
```

The FalseSharing instance is shared between multiple threads and one thread does the following:

```
while(shared.a==0){
    print(shared.b);<== triggers the false sharing
}
```

And another thread at some point calls 'shared.a=1'. Because there is a data race on 'a', the compiler can rewrite the code to:

```
if(shared.a==0){
     while(true){
         print(shared.b);
     }
}
```

This is legal since the JMM mandates that the possible read values of 'a' are {0,1}. And JVM is allowed to produce executions that produce a subset; in this case {0}.

After this code transformation, it is clear that it doesn't matter if 'a' is piggybacking on a falsely shared cache line.

(*) Happens-before consistent is the JMM's solution to prevent undefined behavior in case of a data race. It states that a read needs to see the most recent write before it is in the happens-before order, or a write it is in data race with.

Comment: You seem to have a much deeper understanding on the topic than me, so I'm asking if " Caches on modern CPUs are always coherent." also applies to NUMA systems? Or would that question explode into another multi-paragraph answer?

Comment: Also on NUMA systems. Modern systems typically have partitioned their memory and the cache coherence for each partition is handled by a directory which on Intel/AMD is integrated with the L3 cache; effectively a hashtable where for each cache line the status, owner and sharer nodes are known. All cache coherence traffic for a given cache line is routed to the home node for that directory.

Comment: Cool, so a accessing non-local memory on a NUMA system is "just" slower, but consistency-wise the same as local (if you pardon the pretty steep oversimplification here).

Comment: @JoachimSauer correct.

Comment: Although modern caches are always coherent. The compiler can still mess things up e.g. the compiler could reorder reads of the same field and even though it doesn't matter in a single-threaded application, it can lead to incoherence in multi-threaded applications. The VarHandle opaque access modes or higher solve that problem.

Comment: thank you for your answer. You wrote "Because there is a data race on 'a', the compiler can rewrite the code to", why does it matter that there is data race? I thought the compiler is only allowed to rewrite it that way because a is not volatile

Comment: @alfer, https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs6120/2019fa/blog/threads-not-as-libraries/